# SwiftUI pass parameter to view static function

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, static

I have the following code I have to make sure to pass an error message, if nothing is passed then take a generic message as error.

The problem is that I have to pass it to a `static function` and then set the error but I'm not succeeding.

Can you give me a hand?

```swift
ErrorView.showWindow(error: "La cartella già esiste.") error <-- "La cartella già esiste."
ErrorView.showWindow() error <-- "C'è stato un problema."
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ErrorView: View {
    
    var error: String = "C'è stato un problema."
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image(nsImage: NSApp.applicationIconImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 96, height: 96)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(16)
                .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                .padding(.bottom, 22)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Git Repository")
                        .font(Font.title.weight(.thin))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 14) {
                    Text(error)
                }
                .font(.system(size: 11))
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 24)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .frame(width: 525, height: 200)
    }
    
    static func showWindow(error:String) {
        let viewController = NSHostingController(rootView: ErrorView())
        let windowController = NSWindowController(window: NSWindow(contentViewController: viewController))
        
        if let window = windowController.window {
            window.title = "Title"
            window.titleVisibility = .hidden
            window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            window.animationBehavior = .alertPanel
            window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable]
        }
        
        windowController.showWindow(nil)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}

struct ErrorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ErrorView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find better success here if your comments/error in English

Comment: That won’t work with SwiftUI. You can’t call methods inside a View like that. You can share a ViewModel and have the ViewModel/Observable show an error in the View but what you are trying to do isn’t allowed. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default error message to `showWindow` function instead of ErrorView error var.

Another mistake is you are not passing an error message to your ErrorView.

So final code is

```
struct ErrorView: View {
    
    var error: String //<< Here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image(nsImage: NSApp.applicationIconImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 96, height: 96)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(16)
                .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                .padding(.bottom, 22)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Git Repository")
                        .font(Font.title.weight(.thin))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 14) {
                    Text(error)
                }
                .font(.system(size: 11))
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 24)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .frame(width: 525, height: 200)
    }
    
    static func showWindow(error:String = "C'è stato un problema.") { //<< Here
        let viewController = NSHostingController(rootView: ErrorView(error: error)) //<< Here
        let windowController = NSWindowController(window: NSWindow(contentViewController: viewController))
        
        if let window = windowController.window {
            window.title = "Title"
            window.titleVisibility = .hidden
            window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            window.animationBehavior = .alertPanel
            window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable]
        }
        
        windowController.showWindow(nil)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}
```